# VBA - Copying specific cells given it matches criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Noticed a few similar questions to this, so my apologies if this appears to be repetition - but I have been unable to amend previous advice to suit my needs, given my weak understanding of VBA.

I have two tabs, call them "Raw X" and "X". What I am trying to achieve is:

If Column N in "Raw X" = 4, then don't copy it. 
If Column N in "Raw X" <> 4, then it needs to be copied across to "X"

The tricky part (I think) is that I don't want the entire rows, just certain cells. So from "Raw X", cell C, D, E, K, L and M would need to be copied into "X" cells H, I, K, L, M and N respectively.

The VBA I am working with and trying to amend is below, however it has become far too complex for me once its only certain cells that need to be copied over.

```
Sub RoundedRectangle5_Click()
Dim tfCol As Range, Cell As Object 

Set tfCol = Range("N2:N1000") 

For Each Cell In tfCol 

    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then 
        Exit Sub 
    End If 

    If Cell.Value <> "4" Then 
        Cell.EntireRow.Copy 
        Sheets."X".Select 
        ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select 
        Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select 
        ActiveSheet.Paste 
    End If 

Next 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RoundedRectangle5_Click()
Dim tfCol As Range, _
    Cell As Range, _
    wsRawX As Worksheet, _
    wsX As Worksheet, _
    CellVal As String

With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRawX = .Sheets("Raw X")
    Set wsX = .Sheets("X")
End With 'ThisWorkbook
Set tfCol = wsRawX.Range("N2:N1000")

For Each Cell In tfCol
    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then Exit Sub

    If IsError(Cell.value) Then
        CopyData wsRawX, Cell.Row, wsX
    Else
        If CStr(Cell.value) <> "4" Then
            CopyData wsRawX, Cell.Row, wsX
        Else
        End If
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub

Sub CopyData(SrcSheet As Worksheet, ByVal SrcRow As Double, DestSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim NextRow As Double
    NextRow = DestSheet.Range("H" & DestSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2
    With SrcSheet
        'C and D to H and I
        .Range("C" & SrcRow & ":D" & SrcRow).Copy DestSheet.Range("H" & NextRow)
        'E to K
        .Cells(SrcRow, "E").Copy DestSheet.Range("K" & NextRow)
        'K, L and M to L, M and N
        .Range("K" & SrcRow & ":M" & SrcRow).Copy DestSheet.Range("L" & NextRow)
    End With 'wsRawX
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a "Type Mismatch" Runtime error 13 on the following line:   If Cell.value <> "4" Then. Do you know what the problem might be? Thanks for your help

Comment: @CBooth : It's because it was `"4"` and not `4` and yet you were testing it against a numerical value! It forgot to change it before, try the edit it should work smoothly now! ;)

Comment: still seeing the same problem unfortunately... Any other ideas?

Comment: @CBooth : I've added a line to display the values in Immediate Window, tell what is the last thing that is displayed there! Do you have some *errors* in that column?

Comment: All seems to be okay, all information has pulled over correctly as it should, but just for one line - The error is still a type mismatch in the debugger. Thanks for the help

Comment: @CBooth : What is written in the immediate window? Press Ctrl+G to display/hide it. Paste the result here plz

Comment: Set paper size to -4142
Set paper size to -4142
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
 4 
Error 2042

Comment: @CBooth : As expected the issue is that you have texts and errors in the column, so I've added 2 tests to avoid those values. Do you want to report the line on which there is those values? `Set paper size to -4142` and `Error 2042`

Comment: The paper one shouldn't make a difference. The error ones, yes. Anything that isn't 4. That column is currently a Vlookup to a different sheet, but can be amended to values if needed. Realistically, if its not "4", its likely to be "#N/A"

Comment: Its so nearly there, thanks so much - the only problem left is that it is overwriting the same line rather than going to a new line and editing that. So all the data is getting pasted into H4 etc.

Comment: @CBooth : It's most probably because your column A in RawX wasn't filled, I changed the calculation to be on col H, so it should be good now! ;)

Comment: Seems to be perfect now! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @CBooth : As it solves your issue, please accept the answer and upvote it if you can. You should also go to your profile and do the same for your past questions if they are solved!

Comment: Sorry - one last question. I have an almost identical situation for two other tabs, Raw B and B - would i be able to add this as a new macro underneath, amending for the tab names or will i need to amend the code on it at all? Thanks

Comment: @CBooth : If the data copy is working similarly, you don't have to duplicate the `Sub CopyData`, only the first one to change `.Sheets("Raw X")` to `.Sheets("Raw B")` and same for the line under it! ;) **Btw, I see that you haven't took the tour yet, nor accepted any answers. Please take a minute to look http://stackoverflow.com/tour and go to your profile to accept the answers that helped your solve your questions!** ;)

Comment: Sorry im not sure i understand that... Cant seem to get it pasting on to the "B" tab rather than the "X" tab - thanks for the help - will accept the answers in the next hour or so

Comment: @CBooth : Did you change the name of the second sheet too? `Set wsX = .Sheets("X")` to `Set wsX = .Sheets("B")`? You'll need to change the 2 lines in the `With ThisWorkbook` to change the sheets that are used!